# MySQL hierarchical recursive query

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

I have a MySQL table which is as follows:

```
NCBI_TAXON_ID   PARENT_ID   TAXON_NAME          TAXON_STRAIN    RANK    
1               1           root                                no rank
2759            131567      Eukaryota           superkingdom
6072            33208       Eumetazoa                           no rank
7711            33511       Chordata            phylum
7742            89593       Vertebrata                          no rank
7776            7742        Gnathostomata                       no rank
8287            117571      Sarcopterygii                       no rank
9347            32525       Eutheria                            no rank
9443            314146      Primates            order
9526            314293      Catarrhini          parvorder
9604            314295      Hominidae           family
9605            207598      Homo                genus
9606            9605        Homo sapiens        species
32523           1338369     Tetrapoda                           no rank
32524           32523       Amniota                             no rank
32525           40674       Theria                              no rank
33154           2759        Opisthokonta                        no rank
33208           33154       Metazoa             kingdom
33213           6072        Bilateria                           no rank
33511           33213       Deuterostomia                       no rank
40674           32524       Mammalia            class
89593           7711        Craniata            subphylum
117570          7776        Teleostomi                          no rank
117571          117570      Euteleostomi                        no rank
131567          1           cellular organisms                  no rank
207598          9604        Homininae           subfamily
314146          1437010     Euarchontoglires    superorder
314293          376913      Simiiformes         infraorder
314295          9526        Hominoidea          superfamily
376913          9443        Haplorrhini         suborder
```

The above data is in the hierarchical model. For example, if I want to find the hierarchy of '**Homo Sapiens**'. it linked via **PARENT_ID** i.e. 9605 etc.

```
NCBI_TAXON_ID   PARENT_ID   TAXON_NAME      TAXON_STRAIN    RANK    
9606            9605        Homo sapiens    species
9605            207598      Homo            genus
207598          9604        Homininae       subfamily
.
.
.
1               1           root                            no rank
```

Hope I able to explain the data model properly.

Now I want to retrieve the all the hierarchy by providing the taxon_name i.e 'Homo Sapiens' and in the hierarchical order.

Is it possible to do in MySQL?
Help needed.

Comment: This is possible with `CTE` expressions. Unfortunately, mysql doesn't support it :)

Comment: As above, MySQL doesn't presently have native support for recursion. Options include joining the table to itself as often as could be required, writing a sproc, handling the recursion logic in application code, or switching to an alternativemodel, e.g. nested sets. All of these options have been widely discussed.

Comment: @Strawberry : can you please help me to build the query using stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

[Recursive CTEs (`WITH RECURSIVE`)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive) were introduced in MySQL 8.0 (and [MariaDB 10.2.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/)). Using such an expression, you can achieve what you want quite easily:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE ancestors AS (
    SELECT * FROM taxonomy
    WHERE taxon_name = @desired_taxon

    UNION DISTINCT

    SELECT t.* FROM
        taxonomy    AS t,
        ancestors   AS a
    WHERE t.ncbi_taxon_id = a.parent_id
) SELECT * FROM ancestors;
```

The use of `UNION DISTINCT` rather than `UNION [ALL]` is necessary to avoid an infinite loop once we reach the root record. If you're okay with not having the root record in the result set, or you just don't want it, then you can use the following instead:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE ancestors AS (
    SELECT * FROM taxonomy
    WHERE taxon_name = @desired_taxon

    UNION

    SELECT t.* FROM
        taxonomy    AS t,
        ancestors   AS a
    WHERE
            t.ncbi_taxon_id = a.parent_id
        AND t.ncbi_taxon_id != 1
) SELECT * FROM ancestors;
```

---

Additionally, it appears that records in your dataset have `rank = 'no rank'` if and only if `taxon_strain = ''` (or `taxon_strain` is `NULL`). If this is the case, then your database schema could be simplified by removing the `rank` column and inferring this value from whether `taxon_strain` is defined. Also, `parent_id` should reference `ncbi_taxon_id`, and arguably, the `parent_id` of the root record should be `NULL` — this would also allow your recursive query to not need `UNION DISTINCT` if you want the root record to appear in the result set.

In particular, here is the schema I would use:

```sql
CREATE TABLE taxonomy (
    id          INTEGER UNSIGNED    PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id   INTEGER UNSIGNED,
    name        VARCHAR(32),
    strain      VARCHAR(32),

    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES taxonomy (id)
);

INSERT INTO taxonomy VALUES
    (1               , NULL        , 'root'                , NULL             ),
    (131567          , 1           , 'cellular organisms'  , NULL             ),
    (2759            , 131567      , 'Eukaryota'           , 'superkingdom'   ),
    (33154           , 2759        , 'Opisthokonta'        , NULL             ),
    (33208           , 33154       , 'Metazoa'             , 'kingdom'        ),
    (6072            , 33208       , 'Eumetazoa'           , NULL             ),
    (33213           , 6072        , 'Bilateria'           , NULL             ),
    (33511           , 33213       , 'Deuterostomia'       , NULL             ),
    (7711            , 33511       , 'Chordata'            , 'phylum'         ),
    (89593           , 7711        , 'Craniata'            , 'subphylum'      ),
    (7742            , 89593       , 'Vertebrata'          , NULL             ),
    (7776            , 7742        , 'Gnathostomata'       , NULL             ),
    (117570          , 7776        , 'Teleostomi'          , NULL             ),
    (117571          , 117570      , 'Euteleostomi'        , NULL             ),
    (8287            , 117571      , 'Sarcopterygii'       , NULL             ),
    .
    .
    .
    ( ... );
```

Then your recursive query can be the following:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE ancestors AS (
    SELECT * FROM taxonomy
    WHERE name = @desired_taxon

    UNION

    SELECT t.* FROM
        taxonomy    AS t,
        ancestors   AS a
    WHERE t.id = a.parent_id
) SELECT * FROM ancestors;
```

Such a query is guaranteed to terminate at a row where `parent_id` is NULL, since this is never equal to `id` for any other row, since, as a primary key, `id` must not be `NULL`.